# Never ending loop in openmp section

Tags: c++, openmp

I've got the following code in c++ using openmp 2.5:

```
total = 500;
counter = 0;
#pragma omp parallel
{
    while (counter != total) {
        #pragma omp barrier
        #pragma omp for
        for (it = vec.begin(); it < vec.end(); ++it) {
            work(*it);
        }
    }
}
```

In `work()` I increase/decrease counter in the following way:

```
void increase() {
    #pragma omp atomic
    counter++;
}

void decrease() {
    #pragma omp atomic
    counter--;
}
```

Sometimes the loop never ends however if I remove the parallel pragma code, it works. I suspect I implemented in a wrong way. I need someone expert of openmp code.

Comment: Don't you think the `work` method is kinda relevant to the question?

Comment: at first glance I would look into using `std::atomic<int>` for your counter rather than using the `#pragma omp atomic` unless there is a viable reason. `#pragma omp atomic` may not portable

Comment: It's hard to write all the algorithm here. However the problem is that without the #pragma it works, so I think the code is right but the openmp part is wrong.

Comment: I would assume that since you are using atomic operations that this is being run in a multi-threaded context?

Comment: @AlexZywicki increase and decrease are called in work and so it's exectude in parallel from omp point of view. It's the reason I used omp atomic instead of using std::atomic<int>

Comment: Try changing `counter != total` to `counter <= total` and see what happens.

Comment: @greywolf82 understood, i am not very familiar with omp. I just wanted make sure that using the c++ library features was not a viable alternative

Comment: @AlexZywicki, when it comes to OpenMP, the `atomic` construct is just as portable as `std::atomic<T>`.

Comment: There seems to be no need for the barrier, since there is an implicit barrier at the end of the omp for. (Not that that is your problem, but it should improve performance once you have the code working).

Comment: As it is visible in the MWE the iterator `it` is a `shared` variable which might in turn call the work function in unexpected manners. Also if there is no check for overcounting the change of @HighPerformanceMark might at least give you further assurance where the error comes from